# Chain setup with wireguard in one server

Tags: networking, vpn, wireguard

So I have one server (Server A) and a wireguard tunnel file another for another (Server B). (I can not edit config on Server B)

I want to connect to Server A by wireguard and then pass my traffic through Server B.

Client -> Server A -> Server B -> Internet

First of all by the following config (wg0) I can connect to Server A:

Client config:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = Censored
Address = 10.0.0.3/32
DNS = 8.8.8.8

[Peer]
PublicKey = Censored
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = serverip:port
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

Server A wg0 config:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.1/32
SaveConfig = true
PostUp = iptables -I FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING; iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
ListenPort = port
PrivateKey = Server A private key

[Peer]
PublicKey = Client Public Key
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.3/32
```

Until now I can connect from client to Server A and then connect to Internet.

My question is that How I can pass Client traffic comes to server A through Server B by another wg interface? I don't want to treat Server A as a client for Server B, I want to spilt tunnel just for wg0 interface.

Comment: So you confirm that server A never needs to use its new WireGuard interface (let's call it wg1) to Server B except on behalf of Client? In any case, you should add in the question what configuration Server A is currently using to have a tunnel with server B.